# Missing method in laravel 10 doesn't work?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-10

I'm trying to treat this 404 erro return and I can't do it using the apiResources and Missing method.
For example, I'm doing this:

And whenever it give me a 404 page web error.

Tks!

```
Route::apiResources([
        'survey' => SurveyController::class,
        'user' => UserController::class,
    ])->missing(function () {
        return response()->noContent();
    });
```

Also I have tried this:

```
    Route::apiResource('/survey', SurveyController::class)->missing(function () {
        return response()->noContent();
    });
```

Comment: Check your all the routes using `php artisan route:list`

Comment: You can create `ResourceNotFoundException` and handle it

Comment: hey missing() method works with single request or not please check it once. e.g. try missing method with single method type url like get. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-missing-model-behavior . if it works with get method request url than it seems like bug to use missing method with apiResouce urls

Comment: @Bernan Ribeiro you should have the fallback method on `web.php`

Answer (score 0):

it works only this way.

```
Route::apiResource('/survey', SurveyController::class)->missing(function () {
    return response()->noContent();
});
```

I just forgot we need to run:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Thanks once again!

Comment: If you mark this answer as the right answer it gets removed from the 'unanswered' list

Answer (score -1):

It works if you run php artisan optimize.

Comment: Can you clarify why and what this command is doing?

Comment: Yes, of course. The command will compile routes and views, and it will also clear the application's cache. You need to run it to reflect the changes you have made in your api.php or route.php files.

Comment: Here you have an example on how to use it: Route::get('users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'show'])->missing(function () {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'No user found'], 404);
    });

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it